# how to make sure, including files with opening '/' is secure

Tags: php, security, absolute-path

From your experience, are there any security measures that one should undertake on a VPS before including files with absolute paths (opening /, eg. /common/lib.php or /images/image.jpg)

Comment: If your VPS is properly configured, there should be no need for additional security  measures. Can you elaborate what you are trying to do where? Do you mean real, filesystem absolute paths? Then `/common/lib.php` most likely doesn't make sense

Comment: If you are using absolute paths without user input variables to construct them, you have nothing to worry about. If you are using user input, you need to protect against null-byte errors and the inclusion of `../` in the input path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, there is one for sure.

Make sure that you turned `display_errors` off, to make all the error messages you will get invisible to the user.

Then make these paths real, by adding `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to them or any other way.

And yes, as long as you are using this kind of code

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/common/lib.php';
```

using no dynamically generated filenames

you may consider yourself safe.

Comment: In one of my bootstrap files thats included everywhere, I usually have something like `define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));`. I've never personally been fond of DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: In writing that comment, I realised how silly I've been. Bootstrap now reads `define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);` ... Thanks Shrapnel ;) (although first option works in PHPs prior to 5.3, whereas the second will not)

Comment: thanks guys. I would never include user input as a part of any path syntax. I don't use SERVER vars or APP_ROOT tho. The way I configure the VPS is that Virtual host would make a www.site.com and it's root would be eg. /var/www/site/public. So if there was a common folder in public, I would include it in the code (eg. index.php) as /common/file.php